# what React version of appending to the DOM onClick event>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I want to add `"<li>"` element to the box element onclick the "innerButton", without needing
to ID any element so I can add as many boxes as I need
but how?

```
export default class App extends Component {
    
    render()
    {

      return <>
      Home
      
      <BoxA/>
      <BoxB/>
      <InnerButton name='Enter'/>

    </>
    }
  }



  function InnerButton(arr)
  {
    function addItemToList(newItem)
    {
        // what to do
    }
  
    console.log(arr)
    return <input type={'button'} value={arr.name} }
    onClick={() => addItemToList('item 2')}
    />
  }
function BoxA()
{  

  
  
  return <div id='boxA' >
    <ul>
      <li>
        None.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

}

function BoxB()
{  
  return <div >
    <ul>
      <li>
        None.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
}
```

I tried adding useState ,but I can't use it outside the component ,so can I do it without using states?

Answer (score 0):

store an array of items you want to list in the state at the top level (App), and pass a push function to to InnerButton as a prop, and pass the array to the Box elements.

In the Box element map through the array props and render an `<li></li>` for each element